# Delay when starting Activities

Tags: android

I have a main activity (main menu / home screen)  Most of my game runs on web calls.  When I press a menu option it starts another activity.  My activity calls some xml to build a listview in the onCreate...   Is this causing the delays in launching activities from my main menu?  Is there a method that will allow me load the activity, return the data to the display and then update the listview?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building the listview in itself isn't going to slow things down much. What will slow things down is retrieving the data to populate the listview. If this is a time-consuming process, you should leave the list empty in onCreate and instead start an AsyncTask or other background thread to retrieve the data, wrap it in some kind of Adapter, and only then populate the listview (using a Handler).

In particular, if you are going out onto the web in onCreate, you will need to change the logic for your app to work under Honeycomb; the system will throw an exception if you attempt network activity on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks!  This helped me a ton.  Had no idea about the AsyncTask.  After doing some research I see this is exactly what I needed.